# having issues converting slim to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have this slim syntax:

```
= form_for(@influencer.relationships.build(followed_id: @influencer.id)) do |f|
  div = f.hidden_field :followed_id
  = f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

This is the erb i came up but it doesn't work.

```
<%= form_for(@influencer.relationships.build(followed_id: @influencer.id)) do |f| %>
    <% f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your hidden field needs <%=, not <%

Comment: doh! thank you for that!

Comment: just interesting, what is the reason to convert slim to erb?

Comment: had some slim code that i wanted in erb? everything else i have is written in erb my friend added this code and he writes in slim so i would prefer if it is in erb.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @influencer.relationships.build(followed_id: @influencer.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
<% end %>
```

---

Conversely, it's bad practice to build an object out of the controller scope. `@influencer.relationships.build(followed_id: @influencer.id)` should be done inside the controller:

```
#app/models/influencer.rb
class Influencer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships, foreign_key: :follower_id
end

#app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @influencer = Influencer.find params[:influencer_id]
      @relationship = @influencer.relationships.build #-> "followed_id" SHOULD be a foreign key in the model. If you have it in the model, you won't need to explicitly define it
   end
end
```

Thus, you'll get:

```
<%= button_to "Follow", @relationship %>
```